# How to distinct an object based off multiple attributes

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I am looking for a way to **distinct** an array of objects, the method needs to distinct by two attributes for instance,

```
let arr = [
    {
        name: "George",
        surname: "Hendricks"
    },
    {
        name: "George",
        surname: "Marques"
    },
    {
        name: "George",
        surname: "Hendricks"
    }
]
```

Once filtered should only return an array of 2 objects, **George Hendricks** and **George Marques** As they are unique. Currently I can only filter with **ES6** Set like so

```
let uniArr = [...(new Set(arr))]
```

How can I accomplish my task as fast as possible (working with big data)

Comment: Are the property values really strings?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes they are

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the property values are really strings, you can combine them to make a unique key, and then build a new array using an object (or `Set`) to track the ones you've already seen. The advantage to using an object or `Set` is that you don't have to re-scan the array every time to find out if an entry is unique. Lookup time on them is typically much better (even *dramatically* better) than a linear search.

Here's an example with an object:

```js
let arr = [
    {
        name: "George",
        surname: "Hendricks"
    },
    {
        name: "George",
        surname: "Marques"
    },
    {
        name: "George",
        surname: "Hendricks"
    },
];
let seen = Object.create(null);
let filtered = arr.filter(entry => {
  const key = entry.name + "\u0000" + entry.surname;
  //                       ^---- a string you know won't be in either name or surname
  const keep = !seen[key];
  if (keep) {
    seen[key] = true;
  }
  return keep;
});
console.log(filtered);
```

Or with a `Set`:

```js
let arr = [
    {
        name: "George",
        surname: "Hendricks"
    },
    {
        name: "George",
        surname: "Marques"
    },
    {
        name: "George",
        surname: "Hendricks"
    },
];
let seen = new Set();
let filtered = arr.filter(entry => {
  const key = entry.name + "\u0000" + entry.surname;
  //                       ^---- a string you know won't be in either name or surname
  const keep = !seen.has(key);
  if (keep) {
    seen.add(key);
  }
  return keep;
});
console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: The q seems to be "how to determine value equality for a specific object type". Why do you need the unicode character then?

Comment: @ftor: All characters in JavaScript are unicode characters. :-) As I said in the answer, I used `\u0000` on the assumption it will never appear in either `name` or `surname` and thus makes a good delimiter between the two, avoiding false positives like `name: "ellie row", surname: "hampton"` matching `name: "ellie", surname: "rowhampton"`.

Comment: @AndreMarques: Depending on your use case, you might want `toLowerCase` in the line creating the `key`, so `name: "george", surname: "Martin"` is a match for `name: "George", surname: "Martin"`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The two attributes in the object are supposed to be unique, case included. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use **[`Array.filter()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** to filter the array, by searching over the couple `name` and `surname`.

This is how should be your code:

```
var filtered = arr.filter((person, index, selfArray) =>
  index === selfArray.findIndex((p) => (
    p.name === person.name && p.surname === person.surname
  ))
);
```

**Demo:**

```js
let arr = [{
    name: "George",
    surname: "Hendricks"
  },
  {
    name: "George",
    surname: "Marques"
  },
  {
    name: "George",
    surname: "Hendricks"
  },
];

var filtered = arr.filter((person, index, selfArray) =>
  index === selfArray.findIndex((p) => (
    p.name === person.name && p.surname === person.surname
  ))
);

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: *"How can I accomplish my task as fast as possible (working with big data)"* Constantly re-scanning the array won't be as fast as possible.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, you are right, but this two built-in methods will give a faster result, then re-iterating over the array manually, I know they may take a lot of time, but AFAIK this is the simplest way to do it. But in all cases we need to iterate and check the existence at the same time.

Comment: @chŝdk Thank you for the answer!